# JavaFX Bar Chart Color Change

Tags: javafx, colors, bar-chart

How do I change the color of the bar chart in JavaFX. It's always orange and I can't figure it out. I have literally no clue. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
public void grafikErstellenFuerAuslastungUnterEins() {

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    final BarChart<String, Number> bcMitUnterEins = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
    bcMitUnterEins.setTitle("Traeger, die halten"); // Ueberschrift der Grafik

    XYChart.Series<String, Number> balken = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
    balken.setName("Auslastung in %"); // erscheint unter der Grafik

    // Methode zur Berechnung der Balkenhöhe

    for (int i = 0; i < listeMitUnterEins.size(); i++) {
        balken.getData()
                .add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(
                        listeMitUnterEins.get(i).getTraeger().toString() + "Auslastung: "
                                + Math.round(listeMitUnterEins.get(i).getAuslastung() * 100) + " %",
                        listeMitUnterEins.get(i).getAuslastung() * 100));
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(bcMitUnterEins, 800, 600);
    bcMitUnterEins.getData().addAll(balken);

    gridPane.add(bcMitUnterEins, 0, 0);
    rootPane.setCenter(gridPane);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS code should do the trick:

```
.chart-bar{
    -fx-bar-fill: #000000; /* Whatever color you want */
}
```

This can also be done directly from the java code, no need to create a separate stylesheet just for this if you're not already using one.